# Change of terminals require immigration clearance

Tags: visas, schengen

Am an Indian passport holder. About to tour Greece. Received the Schengen visa from Greek authorities. My flight is from Mumbai to Paris and connecting flight from Paris to Athens. At Paris,there is a change of terminals from 2C to 1. Will I have to go thru immigration? I do not wish to get stuck as Schengen issued is by Greece and it says valid for Schengen stages. It's a multiple entry, C Category 1 month visa. Is it a requirement that there should be first entry to the Schengen state that issued the visa?

Comment: I'll add that this is perfectly fine and quite common. You will go through immigration in Paris because that is where you are first entering the Schengen visa. Greece is also in Schengen, so your flight from Paris to Athens will be treated as "domestic" (as in no immigration controls, because both countries are within Schengen). The authorities in Paris should not have any problem with it, because you are required to obtain your Schengen visa from the "main destination" for your trip, not the state of first entry. If they ask, you can always show them your onward ticket to Athens.

Comment: Just to explicitly mention it, you would also need to go through immigration if you'd stay at the same terminal.

Comment: And just to explicitly mention *this,* you will *not* go through immigration controls in Greece.